# Objective C - Get localised Weekend and Weekday names?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

**What I'd like** is a way of getting separated weekday and weekend names in iOS (localised). I understand that there is NSDateformatter's "weekdaySymbols" method, but this doesn't distinguish between weekend and weekday.

**The problem** I am facing is that different localisations may place their "weekdaySymbols" differently, starting on Monday instead of Sunday for example, so I can't guarantee what index of the array weekend days will appear.

**How can I** do what I'd like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index for `weekdaySymbols` is always the same. 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, etc. through 6 for Saturday. This is the same regardless of the user's locale.

All locales consider Saturday and Sunday to be the weekend. Though some locales treat Sunday as the 1st day of the week while others treat it as the last day. This can be determined from the `NSCalendar firstWeekday` method.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can always assume Saturday and Sunday to be at index 0 and 6?

Comment: That is true (though in reverse). And this all assumes the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: So if the calendar is not Gregorian, there is a chance that the indexes may be wrong? Will forcing a Gregorian calendar still allow weekday names to be localised?

Comment: I have no experience with non-Gregorian calendars. I don't even know if they have 7 days in a week.

Comment: Not correct. Here in Israel, Friday and Saturday are the weekends.